# How to perfectly align line boundries along both the left and right margins

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, layout, browser

I have the following code that uses a pseudo element that works perfectly in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox, Firefox perfectly aligns the lines along the left margin but not perfectly along the right. Without the magic trick, all browsers align the lines along the left margin but make no attempt to do so along the right.

I am already using text-align: justify

HTML

```
    <span class="lb"> fkdjfkdsjfds  fjkdsjfksd. fjkdkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</span>
    <span class="lb">dgggggggggggg  dddddddddddddddddddd  kkkkklllll</span>
    <span class="lb">kkkkkkkkkkkk  dddddddddddddddd  ttttttttt:  dddd </span>
    <span class="lb"> lllllllllll dddddddddddddddddd  ffffffffffffff</span>
```

CSS (No Pseudo Element)

```
.lb{
      text-align: justify;
      display: block;
      width: 390px;
    }
```

This outputs the lines aligned along the left margin: 
https://jsfiddle.net/h0qwbwve/10/

Adding the following psuedo element:

```
.lb:after  {
content: " ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";
line-height: 0;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

I get perfect alignment along the left and right margin in Chrome and EDGE: https://jsfiddle.net/h0qwbwve/11/ -- but it is slightly off at the right margin for Firefox.

I am looking to understand what this pseudo element is actually doing, particularly because I want to build on/adapt it such that it will do the 'right' thing on Firefox and Safari as well or failing that at least gain reason for confidence that the behavior will likely stay the same in Chrome and EDGE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which browsers you need to support, there is no need for a magic trick. There is a CSS property for this, `text-align-last` that aligns the last line of a block the way you want it.

```css
.lb{
  width: 390px;
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  text-align-last:justify;      /* added */
  -moz-text-align-last:justify;
}
```

```html
<span class="lb"> fkdjfkdsjfds  fjkdsjfksd. fjkdkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</span>
<span class="lb">dgggggggggggg  dddddddddddddddddddd  kkkkklllll</span>
<span class="lb">kkkkkkkkkkkk  dddddddddddddddd  ttttttttt:  dddd </span>
<span class="lb"> lllllllllll dddddddddddddddddd  ffffffffffffff</span>
```

But of course, the above works for the latest browsers only. Sometimes you do need a magic trick. The way I was taught was like this.

```css
.lb {
  width: 390px;
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
}
.lb:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 390px;                /* note: same width as lb above */
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="lb"> fkdjfkdsjfds  fjkdsjfksd. fjkdkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</span>
<span class="lb">dgggggggggggg  dddddddddddddddddddd  kkkkklllll</span>
<span class="lb">kkkkkkkkkkkk  dddddddddddddddd  ttttttttt:  dddd </span>
<span class="lb"> lllllllllll dddddddddddddddddd  ffffffffffffff</span>
```